# Showing that $[0,1]$ is compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let's choose an open covering for $\left [ 0,1 \right ]$. For example $$\left \{ \left ( \frac 1 n,1-\frac 1 n \right )  \mid  n\in \{ 3,4,\dots\} \right \}.$$
How can one choose a finite open subcover to prove compactness?

Comment: If your collection of open sets is to be a cover of the interval, it has to cover 0 and 1, which - even given the fact that my browser is not interpreting your formula - seem to be missing from the union of your proposed covering sets.

Comment: Indeed, that is an open cover of $(0,1)$, not $[0,1]$. Since the former interval is not compact, it is not a surprise that there is no finite subcover.

Comment: See here for some other proofs of this fact: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368108/how-to-prove-every-closed-interval-in-r-is-compact

Comment: Read the statement of compactness theorem again. WORD BY WORD.

Answer (score 58):

Here is a quick and elegant proof of the actual result that $[0,1]$ is compact based on [real induction:](http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.0973)

Let $\mathcal{O}$ be an (arbitrary!) open cover. Let $P$ be the set of points $x$ in $[0,1]$ such that $[0,x]$ can be covered by finitely many elements of $\mathcal{O}$. We have $0\in P$ and $P$ is bounded above by $1$. Therefore, $P$ has a supremum $s$.

We first show that $[0,s]$ can be covered by finitely many sets in $\mathcal{O}$. This is trivial when $s=0$, so assume $s>0$. Let $O_s\in\mathcal{O}$ be a set containing $s$. Then there is an $\epsilon \in (0, s)$ such that $(s-\epsilon,s]\subseteq O_s$. By assumption, there is a finite subcover of $[0,s-\epsilon/2]$. By adding $O_s$ to that finite subcovering, we get a finite subcovering of $[0,s]$.

We now show that $s=1$. Suppose $s<1$ and let $O_s\in\mathcal{O}$ be a set containing $s$. Then there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $[s,s+\epsilon)\subseteq O_s$. So taking a finite subcover of $[0,s]$ and adding the set $O_s$ gives us a finite subcover of $[0,s+\epsilon/2]$, contradicting the construction of $s$.

Comment: I am just learning about compactness and I'm a bit confused by the fourth sentence in the third paragraph. How do I know $\exists \epsilon \in (0,s)$ such that $(s-\epsilon,s]\subseteq O_s$? Does this follow from the fact $[0,s]$ can be covered by finitely many sets in $\mathcal{O}$? If so, why?

Comment: @StanShunpike That is basically the definition of an open set. If $O_s$ is open, there must be some "wiggle room" around each of its elements. In particular, if $s\in O_s$ then for some $\epsilon>0$, $(s-\epsilon, s+\epsilon)\subseteq O_s$. The result follows now from $(s-\epsilon,s]\subseteq (s-\epsilon,s+\epsilon)\subseteq O_s$.

Comment: @Michael Greinecker  May I ask a question: Does this argument work in the case of $[0,1]$ as a subspace of $(\mathbb{R},T)$ where $T$ is the topology with bases $\mathcal{B}=\{(a,b]:a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$ ?? I think it does. Thanks in advence!

Comment: @giannispapav No, it does not. Consider the open cover of $[0,1]$ consisting of $(-1,1/2]$ and sets of the form $(1/2+1/n,1]$. It has no finite subcover. If you go through the proof, you see that $s=1/2$. The problem is that the corresponding finite cover, consisting of $(-1,1/2]$ does not extend to a finite subcover of $[0,s+\epsilon]$ for any $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: @Michael Greinecker I see! Thanks!

Comment: @StanShunpike 

Let $O_s$ be an open set containing $s$, then there exists an $\epsilon >0$ such that $(s-\epsilon,s+\epsilon) \subset O_s$ by definition of the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Removing the right hand side of the interval allows us to write $(s-\epsilon,s] \subset O_s$. We also know more specifically where epsilon lives, i.e. $\epsilon \in (0,s]$ because we know that every cover of $[0,0]$ has a finite subcovering, so this constrains the value.

Answer (score 19):

The collection of sets above is not an open cover of $[0,1]$. The points $0$ and the point $1$ are not in any of them.

---

Also you can not prove compactness of anything by taking an open cover and finding a subcover.

The definition of compactness is that for all *open covers*, there exists a finite subcover.

If you want to prove compactness for the interval $[0,1]$, one way is to use the Heine-Borel Theorem that asserts that compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are exactly those closed and bounded subsets.

Comment: Borel actually proved the theorem by showing that each closed and bounded interval is compact...

Answer (score 7):

Answering your question would not prove compactness. The condition for compactness is that *every* open cover has a finite subcover, not just that a single given open cover has a finite subcover. A proof that $[0,1]$ is compact with respect to the Euclidean metric topology can be [found here](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/~john/MT4522/Lectures/L21.html).

Comment: $EVERY$. A very important word.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you would like to prove that it is compact with respect to the usual topology. Since that topology is "generated" by a metric the topological compactness is equvalent with metrical compactness, i.e. the condition stating that every sequence has converging subsequence.

Observe that every sequence of elements of the interval $[0,1]$ is bounded. Therefore, by the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, it has a convergent subsequence.

Notice that the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem can be proved by analytical arguments, so we are not in the vicious circle.

Comment: Proving the equivalence of compactness in terms of open coverings and proving the equivalence with sequential compactness is much, much harder than proving Heine-Borel in the one-dimensional case.