# Topologial properties of $f([1,3]^3)$ where $f(x,y,z)=x^2+2xz+y$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness, connectedness

> If $f(x,y,z)=x^2+2xz+y$, determine $f([1,3]^3)$ and characterize this set in terms of openness, closedness, completeness, compactness and connectedness.

Since $[1,3]^3$ is compact then $f([1,3]^3)$ is, too. How would I go about expressing this function more precisely on this set?

It's obviously not open, closed, compact, complete because it's a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$, and path connected meaning connected.

---

I think I can answer my own, just need confirmation from someone it's just $$[f(1),f(3)]$$
because of compactness and because it's connected.

Comment: You might notice that it is monotonic in each variable separately. The maximum and minimum values are therefore trivial to compute.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the following.

The set $X=[0,3]^3$ is compact as a closed and bounded subset of $\Bbb R^n$ or because the [segment $[0,3]$ is compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368108/how-to-prove-a-b-is-compact/368174#368174) and its power is compact too by Tychonoff theorem. The set  $X$ is linearly connected (and hence connected), because it is convex. The function $f$ is continuous as a composition of different continuous function. Therefore $f(X)$ is a compact connected subset of $\Bbb R$, that is a segment.