# Using the "open cover" definition of compactness to show that $[0,1]$ is compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

How can I prove that the interval $[0,1]$ is compact in real line topology?

I know how to prove it using concept of boundedness and closedness, but I wish to understand it by using the "open cover" definition of compactness: *a set is compact if its every open cover has a finite subcover*.

Kindly help me to see the compactness topologically.

Comment: did you open up a topology book (e.g., Munkres) and read the proof?

Comment: This is called the Heine-Borel theorem, and there's a proof in every single topology textbook, and I'm guessing countless more on the web. Search away.

Comment: All of the proofs there are worth looking at, but the one that you probably want is [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/368169/12042).