# Arguments illustrating advantage of hyperreal definition over sequential one

Tags: nonstandard-analysis

As is well known, fields of hyperreals $\mathbb R^*$ can be formed by
an ultrapower construction, as quotients of the space of sequences of
real numbers by a nonprincipal ultrafilter.  In fact, some arguments
using $\mathbb R^*$ can be reformulated using sequences.  For example,
the nonstandard definition of compactness of a set $S$ is that every
point of $S^*$ is nearstandard in $S$, i.e., infinitely close to a
point of $S$.  This is parallel to the fact that every sequence in $S$
has a subsequence converging to a point of $S$ (an equivalent characterisation of compactness).

Other arguments cannot be reformulated as easily.  For example, one
can prove that a function is continuous at a point $c$ if and only if
it is both right-continuous and left-continuous at $c$.  Namely, an
arbitrary infinitesimal $\epsilon\not=0$ is either positive or
negative.  If $\epsilon>0$ then right-continuity at $c$ implies that
$f(c+\epsilon)\approx0$, and if $\epsilon<0$ then left-continuity at
$c$ implies that $f(c+\epsilon)\approx0$, proving continuity
(according to Robinson's criterion of continuity).  If one tries to
find a parallel argument in terms of sequences, one can immediately
deal with, say, increasing or decreasing sequences in a similar
way, but continuity via sequences would require testing *all*
sequences converging to $c$, and therefore the nonstandard argument
does not translate as cleanly.

Question.  Are there other accessible arguments using hyperreals that
would illustrate the advantage of using nonstandard definitions as
compared to sequential ones?

Comment: Can't you just decompose a sequence converging to $c$ into (if they exist) subsequences consisting of values that are smaller or larger, respectively, than $c$?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, Certainly, one can choose the two subsequences, show that f maps each
to a sequence converging to f(c) based on the hypothesis of one-sided
continuity, and conclude that the original sequence has the same
property.  I imagine this is how it would be done in a textbook using
Heine-type definitions...

Comment: ...Such an argument may or may not be as "clean"
as the hyperreal one, but in any case my main point was to ask for
examples illustrating the advantage of the hyperreal approach over the
sequential one.  Of course, there are advanced examples, such as
models of hyperreals where R is contained in a hyperfinite set, Loeb
measures, etc., which cannot be done in the simple-minded ultrapower
by an ultrafilter over a countable index set (and in particular not
translatable into the sequential framework); but I was hoping to get
some more elementary examples. @MichaelGreinecker

Comment: P.S. I think my proof of compactness of [0,1] is shorter than yours https://math.stackexchange.com/a/189053/72694 :-) @MichaelGreinecker

Answer (score 2):

$
\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}
\newcommand\ext{{}^*}
$

I really like Heine-Borel.

Let $S \subset \mathbb R$. I will use *near* to mean *infinitesimally close*, call elements of $\R$ *standard*, and use *nearstandard* to mean that an element of $\ext\R$ is near some element of $\R$.

- $S$ is *closed* if every element of $\R$ near some element of $\ext S$ is actually in $x \in S$.
- $S$ is *bounded* of $\ext S$ has no infinite elements.
- $S$ is *compact* if every element of $\ext S$ is nearstandard to something in $S$. This is a direct generalization of *finiteness* since $S$ is finite iff every element of $\ext S$ is standard.
- An element of $\ext\R$ is finite iff it is nearstandard.
- If standard $x$ is nearstandard to $y$ then $x = y$.

**Compact $\implies$ Closed+Bounded:** Every element of $\ext S$ is nearstandard by compactness, so there are no infinite elements, so $S$ is bounded. If $x \in \R$ has some $y \in \ext S$ such that $x\approx y$, then by compactness there is a standard $y' \in S$ such that $x\approx y\approx y'$; but that means $x = y' \in S$, so $S$ is closed.

**Closed+Bounded $\implies$ Compact:** Let $x \in \ext S$. Since $S$ is bounded, $x$ is finite and so nearstandard to some $y$. By closure, $y \approx x$ means $y \in S$. Thus $S$ is compact.